# Generating mobile URL for Cognos

Tags: cognos-10

I am new to Cognos right now I am trying to view the reports from mobile,ipad. I have searched for that one I got that I need to create Mobile Configuration setting for that it requires Cognos server url. I don't now how to generate it, can anyone tell the steps to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same URL that you use to access your Cognos BI server over the web or network. This is usually of the form http://cognos_bi_server.example.com/ibmcognos.

Comment: But I am using the following url for viewing reports in network, but the same did not work with mobile.

Comment: url is  pavan:19300/p2pd/servlet/dispatch

Answer (score 0):

I used the fully qualified URl to open reports in mobile
like http://ip address:port/p2pd/servlet/dispatch/m